# More elegant proofs of $\binom a2+\binom b2\leq \binom{a+b-1}2$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs, extremal-combinatorics

I came to know about the inequality
$$\binom a2+\binom b2\leq \binom{a+b-1}2$$
and tried to prove it.

It was quite easy to derive it using brute force algebraic calculations. All boils down to showing
$$a(a-1)+b(b-1)\leq (a+b-1)(a+b-2)$$
about which you can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a*%28a-1%29%2Bb*%28b-1%29%3C%3D%28a%2Bb-1%29*%28a%2Bb-2%29).

But, I want to know whether we can come up with a combinatorial or an intuitive or a geometric explanation. In other words, I am looking for more elegant arguments, or more beautiful proofs of this inequality.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?

Comment: FWIW this can also be stated as the function $\,f(n)=\binom{n+1}{2}\,$ being [superadditive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superadditivity). which is always the case for a quadratic with positive coefficients on $\,\mathbb R^+\,$.

Comment: @SayanDutta I don't bother to ask anymore. They never come out and explain! I have tried :)

Comment: @MathLover sad thing really. These are weird people :(

Comment: @dxiv thanks, I wasn't aware of superadditive functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In fact, you have
$$
\binom{a+b-1}{2}=\binom{a}{2}+\binom{b}{2}+(a-1)(b-1).
$$
A combinatorial interpretation of this is that you have a set $A$ of size $a$ and a set $B$ of size $b$ with exactly one element in common. If two elements are chosen from $A\cup B$ you get either two elements of $A$ or two elements of $B$, and this includes all cases where the common element is chosen, or else you get one element of $A$ and one element of $B$, neither of which is the common element.

Comment: Ah! Nice one (+1)!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for ....

We  simply have to prove the case when $a\ge 1$ and $b\ge 1$ .Note that the term $\binom{n}{2}$ is basically the sum of the first $n-1$ naturals

Thus our inequality becomes equivalent to $$\color{blue}{1+2+..+a-1}+1+2+..b-1\le \color{blue}{1+2+..+a-1}+a+a+1+..a+b-2$$ or $$\iff \color{orange}{1}+\color{red}{2}+..\color{green}{b-1}\le \color{orange}{a}+\color{red}{a+1}+..\color{green}{a+b-2}$$ which is obvious because for each term in LHS there is a corresponding term in RHS which is greater than or equal to  the term in LHS
($\color{orange}{a\ge 1},\color{red}{a+1\ge 2}...\color{green}{a+b-2\ge b-1}$)

Comment: May be another way to say it is, $\frac{a(a-1)}{2}+\frac{b(b-1)}{2}\leq \frac{(a+b-1)(a+b-2)}{2}$. The LHS is sum of first $(a-1)$ natural numbers and first $(b-1)$ natural numbers. RHS is sum of first $(a-1)$ natural numbers and _next_ $(b-1)$ natural numbers.

Comment: @MathLover Ah Nice! Thats a better way to put it I guess

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I was looking for these type of explanations (+1)! Thanks.

Comment: @MathLover that's also a beautiful observation!